# How do I conditionally emit two observables stream?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm wondering any methods can convert one stream to another. I have already got two streams number$ and color$, they output numbers and colors like [1, 1, 1, ...] and ['red', 'red', 'red', ...].

I want to get outputs like [1, 1, 1, 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 1, 1, 1, ...], this output stream will randomly jump number$ to color$ or reversely.

I'm a newbie to RxJS and didn't find an appropriate method to solve my problem. So I assumed a method `jumpWhen(condition, streamJumpTo)`, once the condition is true, the processing stream will be deprecated and it will be converted to a new stream and start to work.

```
let number$, color$

number$ = Rx.Observable.interval(300)
  .jumpWhen(Math.random() > 0.9, color$)
  .mapTo(1)

color$ = Rx.Observable.interval(500)
  .jumpWhen(Math.random() < 0.3, number$)
  .mapTo('red')

number$.subscribe(console.log)
```

The question is, how can I simulate this procedure by using Rx.js v5? Note: $number and $color may have totally different operators appended(not a simple `mapTo`), so I don't think we should try to merge the two streams together.

**Description about this stream:**

At first, stream outputs `1` per 300ms, there is 10% chance to (Math.random() > 0.9) switching number$ to $color. If the switching happens, stream stops outputting `1`, it starts to outputting `red` per 500ms. The overall output may seems like:

```
       1 - - 1 - - 'red' - - - - 'red' - - - - 'red' - - - - 1 - - 1 - ...
cond   f     f       t             f             f           t     f
time  300   600     900           1400         1900        2400   2700
rand  0.5   0.2     0.95          0.99          0.4        0.08   0.1
```

Comment: What happens to the stream if the random number is in between `0.3` and `0.9`? what should be the output?

Comment: @CozyAzure When the current stream is number$, we get a rand per 300ms, if the rand is between 0 and 0.9 stream output 1, otherwise switch to color$ and immediately output 'red'. After switching, the phase is $color, we get a rand per 500ms, if the rand is between 0.3 and 1, stream output 'red', otherwise switch to number$ and immediately output 1. At number$ phase, we have 10% chance switching to color$, and at color$ phase, we have 30% chance switching to number$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Observable.if()`.

`Observable.if(condition, thenSource, [elseSource])` takes in 3 arguments:

1. First argument takes in a function that returns a boolean,
2. Second argument is an `observable` to be emitted if condition is true
3. and the last one being an array of else source, that is to be emitted if condition is false.

Since you have two observables `numbers$` and `colors$`, you can write a the conditional function and decide which observables to be emitted.

```
Observable.if(
    () => Math.random() > 0.5, //function that determines your condition
    number$, //this observable will be emitted if the above function returns true 
    color$ //this will be emitted if false
    )
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

A working [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tayanil/4/edit?js,console).

**Edit:**

From the comments, I realized I understood your requirement wrongly. For your case, you can use `.expand()` operator to repetitively returns an Observable of your choice, and delay accordingly:

```
let test = Observable
.of(1)
.expand((prevData) => {
  let rand = Math.random();
  let number$ = Observable.of(1).delay(300);
  let color$ = Observable.of('red').delay(500);

  if (prevData === 1) {
    return rand > 0.9 ? color$ : number$;
  }
  else {
    return rand < 0.3 ? number$ : color$;
  }

})
.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Edited working [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wevomog/edit?js,console)

Comment: Sorry for ask where is the doc about Observable.if in RxJS 5 ? I found the [doc in RxJS 4](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/if.md), but RxJS 5 docs don't mention Observable.if and no migrating guide about this.

Comment: There are still questions,  following your demo, I still can't implement switching to another stream at different probabilities according to the processing stream. For examples above, if random number great than 0.9 switch number$ to color$, or switch reversely when the random number less than 0.1 and color$ is processing.

Comment: @ZhengJiang `Observable.if` is still in `rxjs5`. Maybe the docs is not updated. Anyway, see the edit.

Comment: Sorry for poor question description, I added the new description about the desired stream and updated the example code(number$ has interval 300ms, $color has interval 500ms). I want to figure out how to write streams to describe the stuff what is called `state transferring metric at probabilities'.

Comment: @ZhengJiang finally understood your question. See if the latest edit solves your problem